# multiple toast for ionic 4

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I want to have multiple toast in ionic framework v4, but idk how to code it

i try to implement multiple toast ionic v3 but its not what i want

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ToastController } from '@ionic/angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'gd-toast',
  templateUrl: './gd-toast.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./gd-toast.component.scss'],
})

export class GdToastComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(public toastController: ToastController){}
  ngOnInit() {
  }

  public toastMsgs: any = [];

  async presentToast(msg) {
      this.toastMsgs.push(msg);
      const toast = await this.toastController.create({
          message: this.toastMsgs.toString().split(",").join("\n"),
          position: 'bottom',
          showCloseButton: true,
          closeButtonText: 'Ok',
          // duration: 3000,       
      });
      toast.present();
      toast.onDidDismiss().then(() => {
          this.toastMsgs = [];
      });
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this way

```
showMultipleToast(msg) {
    this.mytoastController.create({
      message: 'Your messege'+msg,
      duration: 2000,
      animated: true,
      showCloseButton: true,
      closeButtonText: "Done",
      cssClass: "my-toast",
      position: "middle"
    }).then((mobj) => {
      mobj.present();
    });
  }
```